# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection'

Tags: c++, database-connection, psql, libpqxx

When I create an array of connections to psql database using pqxx, connections create successfully and they are in the array. But when I'm going to use one connection it gives me the following error. The way i created the array is also mentioned below. Can anyone tell me the reason for this.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        connection c("dbname=test user=postgres password=abc123\
                     hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
        conList[i]=&c;
    }

  for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            cout<<conList[j]->is_open()<<endl; // this returns 0
        }

conList[0]->activate(); // at this point it gives the following error
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection'
  what():  Connection to database failed
Aborted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing address of local variable `c` in `conList`, after first `for` loop, those local variables are released, `conList` stores **dangling pointers** only, invoke function call to dangling pointers has **undefined behavior**.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{

    connection c("dbname=test user=postgres password=abc123\
                 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
    conList[i]=&c;  // c is local variable
}   // c is released here

for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    cout<<conList[j]->is_open()<<endl;  // undefined behavior
}

conList[0]->activate(); // undefined behavior
```

Consider below change?

store value instead of pointer in `conList`

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{

    connection c("dbname=test user=postgres password=abc123\
                 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
    conList[i] = c;  // make a copy of c
}   

for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    cout<<conList[j].is_open()<<endl;  
}

conList[0].activate();
```

Comment: Thank for your quick response. But when I changed as your suggestion another error occurs. That is 

note: synthesized method ‘pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>& pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::operator=(const pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>&)’ first required here

Comment: Actually, the local variable created in the `for` loop is created and destroyed at each pass through the loop, your wording make it so those objects would live until the full `for` statement ended.

Comment: First time I created the array just like you mentioned. But due to this error I changed the array type to a Pointer and stored the address. Can you tell me how can I overcome this problem.

Comment: @TristanBrindle So how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your `connection c` is created on the stack. When the scope closes (basically, when the enclosing `}` is reached), the compiler runs the destructor for `c`. The connection will be closed, and the address that you've taken and stored in your `conList` now unfortunately points to junk.

The easy way around this is to create a connection on the heap using `operator new`, i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   conList[i] = new connection(/* args... */);
}
```

at some point, when you're finished with the connections, you'll need a matching delete function:

```
for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    delete conList[i];
}
```

---

This is fine, but C-style *raw pointers* are best avoided for a few reasons if you can help it. A better solution would be to store the connection pointer in a C++ *smart pointer*. This will automatically delete the connection at the right time.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<pqxx::connection> connection_ptr;
std::vector<connection_ptr> conList;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    conList.push_back(std::make_shared<pqxx::connection>(/* args... */));
}
```

Now, when the conList is destroyed, all your connections will automatically be closed.

(If you're using C++11, `std::unique_ptr` would probably be a better choice than a shared pointer.)